# Count multiple records with the same id in sql

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So I have a table where I have 
Id, lessonID,studentsID
and I would like to count how many students are on each lesson. 
So how many students have lessonID=1 ,2 etc.
And than display it lessonID and amount of students on this lesson 
I have problem with count() expression

Sample data :

```
ID , lessonID , studentID
1.    1.               1
2.    1.               2
3.     2.              3
```

Expected output

```
LessonID , student amount 
1.                  2
2.                  1
```

Two students have  lesson 1 and one student has lesson 2

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Here you go , i think it's enough.

Comment: Great. Looks like you've already got the answer by GMB.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
select lessonid, count(*) from mytable group by lessonid
```

This means: aggregate records that have the same `lessonid`, and count how many records there are in each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), lessonId FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE lessonID = 1 group by lessonID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select LessonID, count(*) as Student_Amount 
from table 
where LessonID=1 or LessonID=2
group by LessonID;

here first it will display the list of LessonID then it will count the list from table where LessonID=1 or LessonID=2 and count the group of LessonID.